# Having an issue getting saved values from SharedPreference in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that repeats itself six times in an activity (each fragment instance has it own id), and it has a textview that displays a number that users can raise or lower. I am trying to use SharedPreference to save the TextView value as a string, past onDestroy so that users can keep track of the number in the long run. However, something somewhere isn't saving or receiving the values.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //inflates the xml layout
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        //gives the the 0 we need
        nul = 0;

        //setup to use
        frag_text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);
        frag_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_count);
        add1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus_one);
        sub1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_minus_one);
        reset=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);
        buttonl=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.button_layout);

        //automatically hides buttons
        buttonl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //gets the string from sharedpreferences and puts it back
        SharedPreferences pref=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF_COUNT, 0);
        String id=pref.getString("count", nul.toString());
        frag_count.setText(id);

        //rest of the method would go here
}
 @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        //Get the textview so we can get the text from it
        frag_count = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_count);

        //converts frag_count text to string
        String count=frag_count.getText().toString();

        //make the SharedPReference and set it up
        //we also make an editor, add our variable to it and commit
        SharedPreferences pref=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF_COUNT, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edt=pref.edit();
        edt.putString("count", count);

        //commit the edits
        edt.commit();
    }
```

The sharedpreference will set the textview value to 0 on launch, but so far I am unable to save anything. Am I going about this wrong? Anyone mind taking a look and giving me their thoughts, as I am unable to see my issue? Thanks!

EDIT:
changes made according to the suggestion of User3249477

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        frag_count = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_count);
        //gets the string from sharedpreferences and puts it back
        SharedPreferences pref=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF_COUNT, 0);
        String id=pref.getString("count", "0");
        frag_count.setText(id);
    }


@Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        //Get the textview so we can get the text from it
        frag_count = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_count);

        //converts frag_count text to string
        String count=frag_count.getText().toString();

        //make the SharedPReference and set it up
        //we also make an editor, add our variable to it and commit
        SharedPreferences.Editor edt= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).edit();
        edt.putString("count", count);

        //commit the edits
        edt.commit();
    }
```

EDIT 2: I am an idiot, because the application uses the same instance of a fragment six times. It does remember it, but only the very last instance of it.

Comment: When are you saving this values? Is it when you replace the feagment?

Comment: The values are saved whenever the fragment triggers onPause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the default settings:

`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreferences(getActivity()).edit()`

Also do not use `getActivity()` inside onCreateView as the activity might not yet be created and the above method would return null.

And you can get a string of 0 by using `"0"`

Comment: What should I use instead of 'getActivity()' inside the onCreateView to access the values?

Comment: I moved the getValue portion to onActivityCreated(), and I am using the code you suggest above for the saveValue. On launch I get everything set to 0, but if I destroy the application and relaunch it I am not getting any values coming back. I will edit my post above to show these new changes.